# SQL active connections increasing abruptly

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

In my application some time the SQL active connections were increasing abruptly. During the period we can't access the database from Management studio itself.

This problem occurs every 1 hour or 2 hours once and it stands for 20 minutes. I have checked the CPU utilization and RAM utilization, during the period no CPU resources were used. Once the problem resolved all the connections are released and the system start using the CPU resources after that only.

What I need to check for this problem? There is no additional process / program accessing the database during the period.

Comment: Sounds like you're not closing your connections. Check all the places where you're initiating a new connection and make sure the connection is properly closed, even in exceptional states.

Comment: Thanks! I have verified my code, I have closed all the connections once it gets over either success case or failure case.

Answer (score 1):

If you run SQL Server Profiler, to see the sql calls being made, which may give you a clue to the cause?

Comment: I ran the profiler, I found some queries are taking long time to execute. I have shortlisted all the queries and executed the same in management studio. If I ran through management studio it gets completed immediately. It takes long time to complete, only when the SQL connections were high.

Is there any other possible way to check this issue like Indexes, Index corruption, Bad Sector because the database has huge number of data in few tables.